# Angular2 - ngclass on directive selector

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular

I'm using the latest Angular 2 beta (45?) and am trying to attach an ngClass to the element identified by the directive selector.  The variable used to toggle the class does not update.

I suspect it's one of two things:

1. Angular2 just doesn't work that way, so it's a scoping issue; if I
   put a div inside of the directive selector element and attach the
   ngClass to that div, it works.  I'd prefer not to do that though.
2. Because i'm reacting to a window event.  I've tried using Observers,
   setTimeout hackery, and zones.  No luck.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?  Is that just not how it's done anymore?

Sample code written from memory since I do not have access to it presently:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "nav",
    templateUrl: "templates/nav.html"
});

export class NavComponent {
    isOpen:Boolean = false;

    onScroll(e) {
        this.isOpen = true;
    }

    window.onscroll = (e) => this.onScroll.call(this);  // .call seemed necessary, because otherwise the scope of 'this' changed to window instead of the directive  
}
```

**The following does not work:**

*index.html*

```
<nav [ngClass]="{open: isOpen}"></nav>
```

*templates/nav.html*

```
<a href="#">whatever</a>
...
<a href="#">whatever 2</a>
```

**The following does work:**

*index.html*

```
<nav></nav>
```

*templates/nav.html*

```
<div [ngClass]="{open: isOpen}">
    <a href="#">whatever</a>
    ...
    <a href="#">whatever 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: `I'm using the latest Angular 2 beta (45?) ` upvote for laugh.

Comment: haha i know right.  somewhere between 0 and 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isOpen` in

```
<nav [ngClass]="{open: isOpen}"></nav>
```

refers to the parent component of `<nav>`, the component that has `<nav>` in its template.

If you want to set the class on the directives host, use

```
@Directive({
    selector: "nav",
    templateUrl: "templates/nav.html",
    host: {'[class.open]': 'isOpen'}
});
export class NavComponent {
    isOpen:Boolean = false;

    onScroll(e) {
        this.isOpen = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  I bet that'll work.  Is there any performance advantage to doing something like this with host or through a child container?

Comment: No, that's just like `ngClass` but binds to a value on the inside instead of the outside of the directive/component.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Günter's answer, use a [host listener](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DirectiveMetadata-class.html#!#host) instead of assigning an event handler to `window.onscroll`.  Then Angular change detection will run and actually update the CSS class when you scroll.  (Otherwise, some other event will need to happen before the view gets updated.)

```
@Component({
    selector: "nav",
    template: `<a href="#">whatever</a>
      <a href="#">whatever 2</a>`,
    host: {
      '(window:scroll)': 'onScroll($event)',   //  <<------
      '[class.open]': 'isOpen'
    }
})
export class NavComponent {
  isOpen:Boolean = false;
  onScroll(e) {
    this.isOpen = true;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<nav></nav>
    <div *ngFor="#row of dummyArray; #i = index">row {{i}}</div>`,
  styles: ['.open { background-color: lightblue }']
  directives: [NavComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  dummyArray = new Array(100);
  constructor() { console.clear(); }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jyH6pEb25UoW4UNcHCN6?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect.  Once I remembered about hosts i remembered about hostListener and did exactly what you suggested.  Very helpful - thank you.